# EntityFramework DataContext gets SaveChanges gets slower after some time

Tags: performance, entity-framework, datacontext

I've got one datacontext in my application with many threads writing to it.
Thus, the content it holds gets larger and larger and when I save changes the context stays as large (as expected).

Because of it getting larger and larger the SaveChanges duration takes longer and longer.

Are there options to clean the context of changes that have been made to it and saved so that the performance rises again?

Only thing I was thinking of by now was resetting it after some time by re-instanciating my main and only Datacontext instance.

Greetings,

Tim

Answer (score 3):

`DbContext` is designed to be a short-lived object. You should create it, use it, and dispose it as soon as you can.

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{ 
    //do your stuffs

    //call save changes
    context.SaveChanges();
}

//let the using block dispose the context when exit.
```

As everything is relative, maybe your scenario requires more thinking. [Here](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/) is a good post I would recommend to know more about how to properly handle the data context lifetime.

Comment: thank you for your answer. do you have any suggestions how to efficiently save data to a database continously using ef (like f.e. from sensory equipment)? when having data context always just very short lived, since were using a table per type hirachy, it would create redundantly reading the same data over and over again for adding the actually new data to it.

Comment: @Ravior, you're welcome. I think I don't have enough knowledge about your problem, but I can tell you that I've been using short-lived instances to build a notification system and I did create batches and sent insert and update operations asynchronous every 30 seconds, to avoid constantly be writing to the context. And it's working great so far.